# How do you update your match day squad so your players improve or go down on form?

Tags: fifa-13

I'm on ps3 and my squads don't automatically update themselves each week. I have an online pass. Is there a way to do this manually?

Answer (score 1):

Go to edit teams, change squads, and then you'll find an option to download updates.